# How do I get a text box with thicker, non-rounded solid corners?

Tags: tcolorbox, box

[image]I am looking in discussions, but I have not found, a solution to obtain a text box that has the characteristic of having solid corners, that is, a text box with fine lines but the corners of the four sides (not rounded) well marked and in evidence. 
Is there a discussion to refer to here in the forum?
I found extraordinary text box solutions but none with the features I described. Thanks if you can give me a solution and understand how to edit a text box.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Can you add a freehand drawing of the desired result?

Comment: Hi, have you taken a look at the `tcolorbox` package and its `sharp corners` option? You can find its documentation on page 48 in section "4.8 Corners". The manual is available on CTAN for instance (https://ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox).

Comment: You can use the overlay option to draw the corners with a thicker line.

Comment: I uploaded a photo of the solution I would like to get. I hope it helps

Comment: Can you rename your question like for example `How do I get a text box with thicker, non-rounded solid corners?`

Comment: Thanks AndréC for the advice: the title is more appropriate!

Comment: You should accept the provided answer if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Since you do not provide a code for the boxes without reinforced corners, I had to use some code as a starting point. I use [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/377517/194703). However, the new ingredient is

```
overlay={\draw[ultra thick] 
        ([yshift=-1em]frame.north west) |- ([xshift=1em]frame.north west)
        ([yshift=-1em]frame.north east) |- ([xshift=-1em]frame.north east)
        ([yshift=1em]frame.south west) |- ([xshift=1em]frame.south west)
        ([yshift=1em]frame.south east) |- ([xshift=-1em]frame.south east)
        ;}
```

which should work with any box code as long as you load the relevant libraries.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[%
    margin=2cm,
    includefoot,
    bottom=2.55cm,
    top=2.025cm,
    headsep=0.5cm,
    footskip=0.65cm
]{geometry}

\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{0,46,142}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{mytheorem}[1][]{%
    enhanced jigsaw,
    colback=white,
    colframe=myblue,
    coltitle=myblue,
    fonttitle=\bfseries,
    sharp corners,
    detach title,
    enlarge left by=18mm,
    width=\linewidth-18mm,
    underlay unbroken and first={%
       \node[above,text=myblue,font=\bfseries,align=center] at ([xshift=-.5\textwidth,yshift=-7mm]interior.north) {\thetcbcounter};
    },
    breakable,
    pad at break=1mm,
    #1,
    code={\ifdefempty{\tcbtitletext}{}{\tcbset{before upper={\tcbtitle\par\medskip}}}},
    overlay={\draw[ultra thick] 
        ([yshift=-1em]frame.north west) |- ([xshift=1em]frame.north west)
        ([yshift=-1em]frame.north east) |- ([xshift=-1em]frame.north east)
        ([yshift=1em]frame.south west) |- ([xshift=1em]frame.south west)
        ([yshift=1em]frame.south east) |- ([xshift=-1em]frame.south east)
        ;}
}

\begin{document}\raggedright

  \begin{mytheorem}[title=Important Note]
    Important content. A body remains in a state of rest or continuous uniform motion unless acted on by an unbalanced external force.
      \begin{align*}
        45x^2-4x  & =75x
        \end{align*}
  \end{mytheorem}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I had looked at the tcolorbox guide, but I don't know how to solidify the corners and leave the contour lines of the square or rectangle in which to insert the text thin. Sorry .
Thanks Schrödinger's cat! that was exactly what I intended.